# AttributeError: 'KMeans' object has no attribute 'intertia_'

Tags: python, image, error-handling

Not sure why I'm getting this error: AttributeError: 'KMeans' object has no attribute 'intertia_'
Any ideas?

```
distortions=[]
for k_val in k: 
    kmeans=KMeans(n_clusters=k_val,max_iter=100)
    kmeans=kmeans.fit(img_vec)
    distortions.append(kmeans.intertia_)
```

img_vec variable is hsv data from an image & has a shape of (3686400, 3)

Answer (score 2):

It is `kmeans.inertia_` not `kmeans.intertia_`.

Comment: OMG.. lol.. I just did the same typo. Thanks.